# How do I grab input from a text field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
===============
HTML
===============
<div id='game'>
    <form id='user-input'>
        <input type='text' id='guess-value' placeholder='1-100'></input>    
        <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<h4 id='checker'>The value entered is <span id="value">?</span></h4>

===============
jQuery
===============
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var guess = +$('#guess-value').val();
        $("#value").text(guess);
    });
});
```

Above I have shown a snippet of my `html` and `jQuery` code.

I am trying to enter a number into the text field with the `id='guess-value'` and upon clicking on a submit button, 1) store it in a `jQuery` variable called 'guess' and 2) replace the text between the span tags with `id='value'` so I can check that the input is working.

The text between the span tags is not changing, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: need to prevent the form from submitting... google `preventDefault`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var guess = +$('#guess-value').val();
```

try removing the "+" symbol. The "+" symbol will get the code to convert `$('#guess-value').val()` to a number. Instead, use only as following:

```
var guess = $('#guess-value').val();
```

the remaining code seems ok to me.

You can always press F12 on your browser (Chrome or IE) to see the console and check for javascript errors.

Answer (score 1):

This extra `+` sign you have in front of `$('#guess-value').val();` is not necessary. With the `+` sign, you are telling the code to convert `$('#guess-value').val();` into a number.

Change it to this:

```
var guess = $('#guess-value').val();
```

Other than that, your code looks fine.